# svn eclipse on mac uses wrong version of sqlite

Tags: eclipse, macos, sqlite, subclipse

osx big sur (11.2.3)
subversion 1.14.1 (via home brew) - /usr/local/bin/svn
sqlite 3.35.3 (via home brew dependency of subversion) - /usr/local/opt/sqlite/bin/sqlite3
sqlite 3.32.3 (via mac osx) - /usr/bin/sqlite3

if i invoke svn checkout from the command line it works great.

from within eclipse, svn checkout fails:

svn: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
SQLite error
svn: SQLite compiled for 3.34.0, but running with 3.32.3

there are dire warnings about not screwing around with the osx installed sqlite version. how do i get eclipse to use the right sqlite version?

like, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH somehow?

Comment: Same here. Insane because if you `brew uninstall sqlite3` to remove the homebrew version, it says `Refusing to uninstall /opt/homebrew/Cellar/sqlite/3.35.4
because it is required by subversion, which is currently installed`

Comment: `svn --version --verbose` returns :
`- SQLite 3.35.4 (compiled with 3.34.0)` (?????) and 
`- /opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib  - /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`

Comment: But! `python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"` returns `3.32.3` hence that's probably a PYTHONPATH problem ?

Comment: SQlite is coming with my (pyenv) Python installation: `<module 'sqlite3' from '/Users/onekiloparsec/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/__init__.py'>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however not with Eclipse but rather with PySVN. For the reference, I had a subversion installation with Homebrew producing the exact same versions mentioned in your question.

What I did was to install subversion from source. That is:

- `brew uninstall subversion sqlite3` -> this ensure the sqlite3 used is not that of homebrew
- install `scons` (https://scons.org) needed for Apache Serf (not to be confused with `serf` available in homebrew. Note, it builds only with Python2.
- Build Apache Serf with command (inside Serf sources directory): `../scons-local-2.3.0/scons.py APR=/opt/homebrew/opt/apr APU=/opt/homebrew/opt/apr-util OPENSSL=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/`,
- Install Apache Serf:  `../scons-local-2.3.0/scons.py  install` -> will install in `/usr/local` by default
- Build subversion 1.14: `cd subversion-1.14.1` then `./configure --with-apr=/opt/homebrew/opt/apr --with-apr-util=/opt/homebrew/opt/apr-util --with-utf8proc=internal --with-serf=/usr/local`
- Install Subversion: `make` then `make install`
- Then rebuild / install PySvn. And it works.